# Using named postgresql cursor in alembic migration results in psycopg2.errors.InvalidCursorName

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, psycopg2, alembic

I'm trying to write a function that will export large table to the csv file. This function will be run as a part of alembic migration.

Note that I'm using PostgreSQL v12 and psycopg2 v2.9 and sqlalchemy v1.3

```py
def export_data_to_csv(connection: sa.engine.base.Connection, csv_filename: str, table_name: str):
    assert connection.in_transaction()

    with connection.connection.cursor(name="migration_cursor") as cursor:
        with open(csv_filename, 'w', newline='') as csv_file:
            cursor.copy_expert(f"COPY (SELECT * FROM ONLY {table_name}) TO STDOUT WITH CSV HEADER", csv_file)
```

The above function is used in alembic migration file which basically looks like this:

```py
...
def upgrade():
    connection = op.get_bind()
    export_data_to_csv(connection, "exported_table.csv", "<table_name>")
...
```

and the migration file is executed as an online migration defined in `env.py` alembic configuration file

```py
def run_migrations_online():
    """Run migrations in 'online' mode.

    In this scenario we need to create an Engine
    and associate a connection with the context.

    """
    connectable = create_engine(
        f"postgresql://{db_config.user}:{db_config.password}@{db_config.host}:{db_config.port}/{db_config.db}",
        # If an operation can't acquire lock in 60 seconds, we should timeout!
        connect_args={'options': '-c lock_timeout=60000'},
        pool_pre_ping=True
    )
    with connectable.connect() as connection:
        context.configure(connection=connection, target_metadata=target_metadata, transaction_per_migration=True)
        with context.begin_transaction():
            context.run_migrations()
```

Unfortunately, the function does not work correctly. When trying to execute migration via `alembic upgrade`, it gives me an error:

```
  File "<source>.py", line 78, in export_data_to_csv
    with connection.connection.cursor(name="migration_cursor") as cursor:
psycopg2.errors.InvalidCursorName: cursor "migration_cursor" does not exist
```

It seems that I should declare cursor beforehand using other SQL statement, is it correct?
If yes, how can I do it?

Comment: Why are you using a [named cursor](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#server-side-cursors) at all?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver The table I want to export stores a few million of records and when I try to load all its records from the database, something is killing (probably OOM killer in AWS kills backend that handles my request)  my session, so I want to try to batch this operation on the server side

Comment: I don't see that happening using `psycopg2` and `copy_expert`. Pretty sure `cursor.copy_expert(f"COPY (SELECT * FROM ONLY {table_name}) TO STDOUT WITH CSV HEADER", csv_file)` is just going to stream everything directly to the file. I would test using subset of table and directly using `psycopg2`, not through Alembic. You might have better luck with `psycopg3` and its [COPY](https://www.psycopg.org/psycopg3/docs/basic/copy.html). See *Copying block-by-block*.

Comment: I thought that on the server side, the whole query gets loaded anyway in the backend, and since the `SELECT * FROM table` query was killed I assumed it would be the same with the copy_expert :p

Comment: Oh no, the copy_expert without name also does not work :/ after copying about 50 000 rows it raises an error `psycopg2.DatabaseError: error with status PGRES_COPY_OUT and no message from the libpq`

Comment: Best guess some sort of connection/network timeout closing  the flow of data. Look at the Postgres log to see what it says.